# Jquery ui draggable, drag parent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

As the title says i want to drag div parent, let's say i have this structure

```
<div class="parent">
  <divc class="draggable"></div>
</div>

$(".draggable").draggable();
```

So how can i drag `.parent` instead of `.draggable`.

And no, i don't want to make `.parent` draggable instead of `.draggable`, since it's gonna be a window which will only be draggable in one place.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Are you trying to make the child element a drag handle?

```
$(".parent").draggable({ handle: ".draggable" });
```

This would make it so the whole parent drags but but only uses the draggable div as an anchor.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cbz36j9k/)</kbd>

Reference:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle

Comment: yup!  nice.  One line of code and got what I needed.  @specman thank you.